# Why can't Svelte recognize the images folder?

Tags: html, image, svg, svelte

I have a Svelte project.

I want to add images in the website. The images are stored in an "images" folder in the "src" folder. But when I type the below code in a component which is in "src/components", the images don't appear.

```
<img src="pic.svg" alt="Pic Name" />
```

Here is a picture of the folder structure:
[image]
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: pap of the folder structure

Comment: @SherifSalah what?

Comment: Post A Picture of your folder structure.

Comment: @SherifSalah I just posted the picture of the folder structure

Answer (score 4):

The `src` folder is not served in the final build. You will need to put your `images` folder in the `public` one. You will be then able to use your images like:

```html
<img src="images/pic.svg" alt="Pic Name" />
```

Comment: I moved it to a static folder but it still did not work

Comment: @niyojet344 Just tried with sveltekit `v1.0.0-next.174` and it works well. The `static` folder should be at the root of your project not in `src`.

Comment: @niyojet344 not sure if i can add sveltekit to an already existing svelte app

Comment: @niyojet344 Sorry I miss-read your question and thought you were using sveltekit. With a svelte project you need to put your static content in the `public` folder to be served. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the **`static`** folder inside of the **`public`** folder to be accessible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in before the the link of source, one dot and slash.

```
<img src="./pic.svg" alt="Pic Name" />
```